# Can dotnet-test specify a runtime-identifier?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to use [dotnet test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test), but I would like to be able to specify a [runtime identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog). Specifically, I need to run my unit test in 32-bit mode (RID `win-x86`). I am able to set the RID using `dotnet run`, `dotnet publish`, etc. but `dotnet test` doesn't seem to support this. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it, according to the docs.

> > dotnet test --help

```
Usage: dotnet test [options] <PROJECT | SOLUTION> [[--] <RunSettings arguments>...]]

...
Options:
  --runtime <RUNTIME_IDENTIFIER>           The target runtime to test for.
...
```

So in your case, it should be:

> > dotnet test --runtime win-x86

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh. Interesting that this is not mentioned in the online docs themselves. That helped, but now I am getting `BadImageFormatException`. It claims it cannot load or discover any tests.

Comment: I guess you must add the target framework you want to test against to the .csproj file.

Comment: You Sir saved my life. The official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21 did not!